# Scale Up/Down all Elements, Images, Text when browser window width is changed

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to scale down/up all elements including texts, images, etc. depending on the browser width? It is like 'zooming out' using your browser just to avoid the browser horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though it requires JavaScript and doesn't work with all browsers, only those which support CSS zoom (which I know at least Firefox does not).  How I do it, is say the standard non-zoomed page width is 1024, I use jQuery with the line

```
$("html").css("zoom",window.innerWidth/1024);
```

every time the window is resized (using window.onresize).  The site I'm using it on is still non-public so I can't show you the example, but it works pretty well.

Comment: This is JavaScript, which is not mentioned in the tags, and doesn't work with all browsers. Why is this the accepted answer?

Comment: This works, but the other answer is better (see my comments there)

Answer (score 3):

You can resize **images and video** with just this css rule.

```
img, video { max-width: 100%; }
```

For **text**, you can work with `em`'s to adjust to the viewport and resolution. You should also set the font size on the html and body element

```
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}

body {
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* Adjust the font size here to upscale the font when you've resized the page to 700px */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    html { font-size: 110%; }
}
```

If you're actually thinking about **literally zooming in/out** for certain viewports, just use media queries. Like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 400px) {
    /* some funky stuff */
}
```

**EXTRA**

To smoothen the transition between different viewports, use this css property on the `html` tag

```
transition: all 1s ease;
```

Comment: @Perroquiet This is actually the correct answer, except that the `vw` unit should be used on the html `font-size: 1vw`. Try to expand/shrink the browser on [http://oneapi.ru/showcases/](http://oneapi.ru/showcases/)

Comment: Actually, I meant on `body { font-size: 1vw }` instead of `html`, and have all the site defined in relative measurements with `em` as can be checked in the aforementioned site.